# apply react-boilerplate with sigma primereact template

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-boilerplate

I am looking for solution to implement (apply) [primereact sigma](https://github.com/primefaces/sigma) template to [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) code.
My router looks like:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route exact path="/User" component={UserPage} />
    <Route exact path="/EditUser" component={EditUserPage} />
    <Route exact path="/Login" component={LoginPage} />
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
</Switch>
```

I applied the template code in containers/App/index.js. For now the HomePage, UserPage and EditUserPage is showing exactly as expected.
But the LoginPage is show beside the Navbar, i want this LoginPage to show without template navbar, just the LoginPage.

[image]

I put my code at [sample](https://github.com/cumibulat/PrimeJ2H)
Maybe someone could show me example or guide how to accomplish goal to implement sigma template.